# jQuery toggle() on element previously moved via appendTo

Tags: jquery, wordpress, toggle

In my WP custom menu I want to add some dynamic submenu (with an `id` of "submenu") under the `li` element with a `class` of "item_collection":

```
$( '#submenu' ).appendTo( 'li.item_collection' );
$(document).on('click','li.item_collection a',function() {
    $( '#submenu' ).toggle();
    return false;
});
```

The "submenu" element gets moved as expected (first line) but the rest below doesn't do anything, I click and nothing happens. Why?

Comment: Can you post your code in jsfiddle?

Comment: Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/fhuhyjux/1/

Answer (score 0):

The `.on()` method is not available in jQuery version 1.6.4. You either need to update jQuery to a more recent version (afaik 1.8 or newer) or use an old method (like `.bind()`) which will be available to you in v1.6.4. Upgrade is preferable imho

Older version:

```
$(document).bind('click','li.item_collection a',function() {
    $( '#submenu' ).toggle();
    return false;
});
```

Newer version: http://jsfiddle.net/fhuhyjux/2/

Comment: Actually I'm using default WP jQuery version which is 1.11.1 (I'll never understand why WP uses old versions of jQuery), and it doesn't work with that version, at least on my computer.

Comment: @drake035, I just refered to your fiddle, not to your WP. Does my fiddle work for you?

Comment: What does the browser console say?

Comment: Well in the Firebug console tab where JS errors appear I see no JS error.

Comment: I don't know then, tripple check everything :) Don't know how I can help further